# how do I check if a bind mount on linux is private or shared?

Tags: filesystems

The mount command allows us to make a bind mount shared, slave, shared+slave, private or unbindable, however, I was unable to figure for a given mount point what is type of subtree rooted at the bind-mount (shared, slave, private, shared+slave or unbindable). How do I find if a bind mount is a slave or private?

Answer (score 16):

The answer is in the [`mount(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) manual page as well:

> Use findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION to see the current propagation flags.

An example:

```
$ findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /opt
TARGET PROPAGATION
/opt   shared

$ sudo mount -o bind /opt /mnt
$ sudo mount --make-slave /opt
$ findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /opt
TARGET PROPAGATION
/opt   private,slave

$ sudo umount /mnt
$ findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /opt
TARGET PROPAGATION
/opt   private
```

Check the [`findmnt`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/findmnt) manual page for other options.

For reference, these examples are using:

```
$ findmnt --version
findmnt from util-linux 2.27.1
```

Comment: Which version `findmnt` are you using? I am using `findmnt` on Ubuntu 14.04 and that doesn't seem to have the "PROPAGATION" option.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively to *dawud*'s answer, you can directly ask the kernel like this:

```
# cat /proc/1/mountinfo
14 19 0:14 / /sys rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:7 - sysfs sysfs rw
15 19 0:3 / /proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:12 - proc proc rw
[...]
```

You can see from the 7th field that my `/sys` filesystem is *shared* (just like `/proc`).

Also, it is in peer group 7 (mounts in the same peer group propagate events to each other).

The number in `/proc/1/mountinfo` is the PID of a process, because processes can be in different mount namespaces and "see" different results. You may want to use another PID, i.e. if you are working with containers. Otherwise, `1` is simple and straightforward.

Shared mounts are [available](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=03e06e68ff76294e53ffa898cb844d2a997b043e) since Linux kernel version 2.6.15.

Answer (score -2):

It's 2 views of the same data, modifications in one reflects in the other

mount --bind /source /destrination

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount

mount binds are just of way of ordering a filesystem view to your own preference

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks how to find the mode of a given bind-mount (shared, slave, private, etc.) not to define what a bind mount is.

Comment: the link provided explains, it is none of the above

Comment: @Rob-d what do you mean by "it is none of the above" ? As Cosmic Ossifrage pointed out my question what about the type of mount, not how to use the bind mount.

Comment: It is whatever type you are bind mounting from, otherwise use bindfs -r etc.